# Save Google map to jpeg using MFC?

Tags: mfc, google-maps-static-api

I have read some doc about Static Maps API V2, it can display a static map image in browser.

I want to know how to save as this image by the map URL directly.

thank your!

Answer (score 0):

The url to the map is a direct link to a `PNG` file, so just download it and save as a bitmap file.

```
void TestDlg1::OnButton1() 
{
    LPCTSTR pszMapUrl = 
        _T("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap")
        _T("?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY")
        _T("&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color")
        _T(":blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label")
        _T(":G|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red|color:red|label:")
        _T("C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false");

    LPCTSTR pszLocalfile = _T("c:\\Temp\\Map01.png");

    HRESULT hr = ::URLDownloadToFile(NULL, pszMapUrl, pszLocalfile, 0, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))     AfxMessageBox(_T("Error in saving map !"));
}
```